# How to Show the Content of a Variable Which is in a Class Library In A Form Or Console?

Tags: c#

I have a C# solution which contains a project and a class library written by somebody else. The class library gets GPS data via wifi. The project shows the processed data on a map. Now, I want to see the contents of some variables in the class library in real time for the sake of debugging.

I tried to use

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(value)
```

without success. It seems it does not do anything.

Also I tried "MessageBox.Show(value.ToString())" which was good but it stopped the wifi reading and interrupted the program as I needed to press OK button each time that it showed up.

Moreover, I added a windows form (which contained a textBox) to the class library to print the data in the textBox, however, when I wrote:

```
Form1.textBox1.Text = value.ToString()
```

It gives me this error:

> Error 3   'MapNMEA.Form1.textBox1' is inaccessible due to its protection level    C:\Users\john\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\new ver of map purecom\MapExplorer\MapExplorer\MapNMEA\MapNMEA\SerialPort.cs    184 27  MapNMEA

"MapNMEA" is the name of the class library. Also "MapExplorer" is the name of both solution and the project. "SerialPort.cs" is a file inside the class library in which I wrote the above code.

My question is how to show the content of those variable (they are 3,4 variables) in real time and this act should not stop the wifi reading. I need to do this as an electrician who does not know much about programming wants to check whether a GPS device sends the data to my computer correctly or not.

**UPDATE 1**: Actually I noticed that `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(value)` is working but as there was too many warning messages showing up in the debug window, I did not noticed it. Now, if somehow I could remove (or hide) other (warning) messages, I would see only my desired output. Do you know?

Comment: What about writeline doesn't work? Have you read the documentation? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline.aspx

Comment: @asawyer: no, it did not work as well. Maybe the prompt window closes so fast that I don't see it at all. I can't use Read() as I don't want to stop wifi reading.

Comment: You can create a listener that automagically writes to a log file. It's in the link.  See the examples section; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.defaulttracelistener.aspx

Answer (score 1):

`Debug.Write` should be fine if you attach a listener first (`Debug.Listeners.Add( new _a_listener_type() )`).

Also, you should probably be aware of the `AutoFlush` property on the `Debug` class which determines whether or not `Flush` is automatically called.

Comment: Where should I add the listener ?

Comment: Once, somewhere *before* you try to write something to Debug.

Answer (score 1):

`Debug.Write` should work - by default it will write to the 'Debug' window in Visual Studio if you have the debugger attached. Are you sure you're looking in the right place?

If you want to use the form approach, you need to keep track of the instance of the form which is open, and give it a public method. For example:

```
public void WriteDebug(string message) {
  TextBox1.Text += message + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Then you can call `formInstance.WriteDebug(message);`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may not be searching the right location: Is there something preventing you from debugging on a PC first before going to a target? If not, the you should probably use the traditional way: put spies on variables, use your IDE (Visual Studio) to watch them and so on.

If you actually NEED to run on target without advanced debug tools, then you might want to take a look at some easier solutions:

- log them to a text file (append or replace, whatever you need), then have a viewer opened at hand
- make another non-modal form with a textbox, and call a form2.writeDbgTextBox(String) every time you need to refresh

Be sure to remove this code on release (eg. by putting them in a #if DEBUG section)

And whatever happens, DO NOT try to write to an existing Message box! they are made to pop up and close, not to interact with your code.

Comment: In the your last line, from "textbox", you mean "MessageBox"?

Answer (score 0):

Do you run debug build? Also your code with textbox does not work, because `textBox1` is non-public